# serializing and unserializing session array

Tags: php, codeigniter, serialization

This is my code for saving purchase order form to database..

```
function save(&$purchase_data,$purchase_id)
    {
        $success=false;

        //Run these queries as a transaction, we want to make sure we do all or nothing
        $this->db->trans_start();

        if($purchase_data)
        {
            if (!$purchase_id or !$this->exists($purchase_id))
            {  
                //$purchase_data['purchase_id'] = $purchase_id = $purchase_data['purchase_id'];
                $success = $this->db->insert('purchase_order',$purchase_data);
                $post_array['cart']=$this->session->userdata('data');
                /*print_r($post_array);
                exit;*/
                $purchase_id=$this->db->insert_id();
                $i=0;
    foreach($post_array['cart'] as $item)
    {
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($item); echo "</pre>";
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM phppos_items WHERE item_id='".$item['product_id']."'");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $product_name=$row->name;

}
        $product_id=$item['product_id'];
        $quantity=$item['quantity'];
        $unit=$item['unit'];
        $unit_rate=$item['unit_rate'];
        $query = $this->db->query("insert into phppos_productdetails(product_id,product_name,quantity,unit,unit_rate,purchase_id) values ('$product_id','$product_name','$quantity','$unit','$unit_rate','$purchase_id')");

        $i++;
    }
            }
}
```

Now this code insert multiple rows in productdetails table but I want to serialize $post_array['cart'] array and want to store whole array in one column. So how do I do it??
Now My data is saving like following..[image]

You can see three products with purchase_id 17.So I want to store all product_id's, all product name, all qty,unit,unit_rate in one column. In short I want to insert only one row to database. So what changes should I make to foreach loop??

Answer (score 1):

you can serialize array or object with php serialize function, it will return you a string which you can save in you table varchar or text type column better to create text type column string can be long if array is long, a simple example

```
$val = serialize(array('test','test2',"test3",'test4'=>'1'));

or 

$val = serialize($post_array['cart']);
```

when you get column from table you can unserialize the string it will give you array back

```
print_r(unserialize($val));

or 

$cart = print_r($row->column_name);
```

you can loop through the cart as you are doing right now.

Comment: yes create a multi dimensional array of all items for purchase_id 17 serialize the array and save in table it will be array('itme1'=>array(all info),'item2'=>array(all info),'item3'=>array(all info)); and serialize it

Answer (score 0):

These functions (from [PHP Session helpers](https://gist.github.com/fdorantesm/6794f12069fb7ff822b474a5502de613)) may help you:

```
function decode_session($data){
  $temp = $_SESSION;
  session_decode($data);
  $out = $_SESSION;
  $_SESSION = $temp;
  return $out;
}

function encode_session($data){
  $temp = $_SESSION;
  $_SESSION = $data;
  $out = session_encode();
  $_SESSION = $temp;
  return $out;
}
```